# How to notify subcribers when an instance of a class held in a store is mutated

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

I'm able to hold an object in a store and mutate it by cloning and replacing the object, for example:

```js
$store = someObject; // Notifies subscribers if someObject was not already the value of the store
someObject.property = newValue;
$store = {...someObject}; // Notifies subscribers because we're assigning a new object
```

However, this does not work for an instance of a class because the prototype (methods) are not copied. The store ends up with an object rather than an instance of the class.

I'm looking for a way to trigger notification after mutation, something like:

```
$store = someClassInstance;
someClassInstance.mutateSomeProperties();
store.forceUpdate();
```

My experiments calling `store.set()` and `store.update()` fail to notify subscribers of a change, presumably because (as stated in the [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_store)) this only happens when the value being set changes. I am though confused by this [PR](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/2190) which seems to contradict that, and gives me some hope there is a way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a not too hacky solution, but if this is the only way I think it would be better to support this capability in the store API.

What I am now doing is wrapping the instance object in a proxy object and replacing the latter. It means I have an extra de-reference, but this is not so terrible:

```
$store = {theInstance: someClassInstance}; // Notifies subscribers
someClassInstance.mutateProperties();
$store = {theInstance: someClassInstance}
```

And to use the `store`:

```
$store.theInstance.doStuff();
```

Although you may need to be careful using this in component scripts if you get errors related to `undefined`. In which case check `$store && $store.theInstance` before using.